# How to insert copied range which contains discontinuous rows into other places？

Tags: excel, vba

It is a simple question. 
For example I have rows(1) rows(3), I can union them into same range. I can paste them But I can't insert them !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with the [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx). The Areas are the contiguous rows that make up the [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx).

```
Sub insertAreas()
    Dim a As Long, rng As Range
    Set rng = Union(Rows(1), Rows(3))
    For a = rng.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
        rng.Areas(a).Copy
        Rows(10).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next a
End Sub
```

I've reversed the order of the Copy/Insert to maintain the original order.

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I want! But I'm kind of curious that why they don't let us simply use the insert method as the continuous range can

Answer (score 0):

Hope that I understand your meaning. Excel only can insert continuing copied row. This rule apply on Excel not only VBA.

I would suggest you use `selection.count/32768` to get the number of row selected. and then you write some code to insert the number of row and then paste the selection instead of directly insert.

say, if you want to copied rows 1 and 3 to row 5.

you can

`set myRng=Range("1:1,3:3")
runNum=myRng.count / 32768
for i = 1 to runNum 
  rows(5).insert
next
myRng.copy rows(5)`

Comment: Yeah, you totally get me. Thanks a lot. But I just curious why Excel doesn't allowed discontinuous rows to be inserted continuously. That really just make things complicated